# React: useEffect to only invoke when data changes

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have a multipage application. When i click between `dashboard/global` and `dashboard/my-posts` useEffect is invoked. Thus, my application is constantly calling my fetch and taking a while to load.

Is there a way to only invoke useEffect when new data is being has been found?

I tried adding myRecipes and AllRecipes to the useEffect dependency but `track promise`'s loading indictator is running infinitely.

```
import React, {
  useState, useEffect, useContext, useMemo,
} from 'react';
import { v1 as uuidv1 } from 'uuid';
import { trackPromise } from 'react-promise-tracker';
import LoadingIndicator from '../utils/LoadingIndicator';
import DashboardHeader from './DashboardHeader';
import '../App.css';
import Post from './Post';
import CreateForm from '../create-recipe/CreateForm';
import RecipeService from '../../service/RecipeService';
import { AuthContext } from '../../context/AuthContext';

export default function Dashboard() {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [allRecipes, setAllRecipes] = useState([]);
  const [myRecipes, setMyRecipes] = useState([]);
  const currentUrl = window.location.pathname;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUrl === '/dashboard/global') {
      trackPromise(
        RecipeService.getAllRecipes()
          .then((data) => {
            setAllRecipes(data);
          }),
      );
    } else if (currentUrl === '/dashboard/my-posts' && isAuthenticated === true) {
      trackPromise(
        RecipeService.getRecipes()
          .then((data) => {
            setMyRecipes(data);
          }),
      );
    }
  }, [currentUrl, allRecipes, myRecipes]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="dashboard">
        <DashboardHeader />
        {currentUrl === '/dashboard/my-posts' && !isAuthenticated
          ? <h2 className="dashboard__unauthenticated-msg">Please Login To See Your Recipes</h2>
          : null}
        <div className="created-posts">
          {currentUrl === '/dashboard/global' && allRecipes
            ? allRecipes.map((recipe) => <Post recipe={recipe} key={uuidv1()} />)
            : null}
          {currentUrl === '/dashboard/my-posts' && myRecipes.recipes
            ? myRecipes.recipes.map((recipe) => <Post recipe={recipe} key={uuidv1()} />)
            : null}
          {myRecipes.recipes && allRecipes
            ? null : <LoadingIndicator />}
        </div>
        {currentUrl === '/dashboard/create' ? <CreateForm /> : null}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you remove allRecipes and myRecipes from the dependency list? setAllRecipes is probably causing allRecipes to change, which in turn causes the useEffect hook to be triggered.

Comment: I tried that in the first place. But what if i wanted useEffect to check if whether allRecipes and myRecipes changed?

Comment: Is this useEffect hook the only place where allRecipes or myRecipes would be changed? If so, is there a reason you couldn't check within this hook in the then() sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a function depending on source data whether it changed or not, I would recommend you to use [selectors](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) with redux.

In short, selectors are memoized functions that detect changes to the current parameter.

Comment: I agree... i was going to start with redux anyways, so perhaps i will do so now. But how is that different from using react's useMemo.. Im just making a guess, that the difference between redux and usememo is that redux is global?

Comment: I think you’re a little confused. You meant useContext instead of useMemo, right? Anyway, I do recommend you to read the React docs, especially about hooks: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html. Redux is used to store data of your app. It’s easy to understand its concept. You can also find information about it: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts.

Answer (score 1):

A better architecture could help you to solve the issues with this component. You should use a router and load different components when the URL changes. Then you can make the appropriate API call, and render the appropriate JSX for that page.

`AllRecipes` and `myRecipes` should not be dependencies of that useEffect, because when it is invoked it will updated those states and trigger itself again.

Comment: that could be an option, but given that both have the same jsx layout/css, i feel like there isnt a point to duplicate my code if i know it can be done in one.

Comment: you would create a shared component and import it into each of those containers. Then your code is shared, but not duplicated.